# Scala type mismatch with Traversables

Tags: scala

I am trying to write a function that takes an Traversable of functions, and a Traversable of values, and returns a Traversable of functions applied to those values.  I am getting a type mismatch error when I try to call the function on a list and a vector.  Here is my code:

```
def applyFunctions[A](x: Traversable[A => A], y: Traversable[A]): Traversable[A] = {
  for (ys <- y; 
       xs <- x
       ) yield (xs(ys))
}
```

And then I try and call this function using this:

```
transform(List({(x: Double) => x + x}, {(x: Double) => x * 2}), Vector(1,2,3))
```

And I get the following error:

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[Double => Double]
 required: Traversable[AnyVal => AnyVal]
```

I thought that List was a subclass of Traversable, so I could able to use Traversable in the function definition.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Vector* is interpreted as *Vector[Int]*, you can declare it as *Vector[Double]* since it should have the same type as the type A in the functions, which is *Double*:

```
applyFunctions(List({(x: Double) => x + x}, {(x: Double) => x * 2}), Vector[Double](1,2,3))
// res9: Traversable[Double] = Vector(2.0, 2.0, 4.0, 4.0, 6.0, 6.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Type parameter `A` is deduced from all arguments of function. Your first argument has type `List[Double => Double]` however second argument is of type `Vector[Int]`. Common ancestor of `Double` (`A` from first argument) and `Int` (`A` from second argument) is `AnyVal` and that's why it is final value of `A`.

To fix your issue, change `Vector(1,2,3)` to `Vector(1.0,2.0,3.0)`.